# Prevent external event drop on month view in scheduler

Tags: fullcalendar-scheduler

Here's a problem that's easy to see in the standard demo for fullcalendar-scheduler showing external event drag-n-drop here:

https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.6.2/demos/external-dragging.html

Placing an event properly onto the calendar requires grabbing an event from the far left and dropping it onto the correct room and time. However, the rooms are not displayed in either the week or month views.

The problem is that you can still drag an event onto the calendar in week and month view, but there's no way to select the room in those views so you're just creating errors. Try this. Go into Month view, drag an event over to the calendar and it appears where you dropped it. Now go back to the Day or 3 Day views and the event you just dropped is not visible since it's not associated with a valid room.

So, the question is, how can I disable drag/drop based on the view?

I tried using dropAccept with a function (something like if view=month return false), but dropAccept doesn't seem to know the current view.

I'm not positive, but I think both drop and eventReceive are called after it's too late and the event is already on the calendar.

Answer (score 1):

By doing it on those views, you're not creating an error as such, you're just adding an event which doesn't have a resource associated with it. Therefore it won't show up in a resource-aware view. Remember that scheduler is just an add-on to the main fullCalendar product, so there are views in existence (including month and week) which are part of the main product, and thus are not resource-aware, because the resource concept doesn't exist in that product.

You can make the week view resource-aware by following these instructions: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical_resource_view/getting_started/, but there's nothing you can do about the month view (simply not enough space in the view to make the GUI workable).

Having said that, you can use the getView https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/getView/ method anytime to ask the calendar what the current view is, and use that info to decide whether to prevent them from dragging onto that view, or you could even pop up some extra UI of your own to ask them to choose a resource, and then add the resource manually to the event data before adding it to the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Use [custom view config options](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-specific-options) in fullcalendar settings:

I.e. `views.week.droppable = false`